# $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} -\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ and the problem of $\infty-\infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, infinity, indeterminate-forms

I'm trying to calculate

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} -\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$

but I'm having the problem of getting

$$\infty - \infty$$

which I read to be indeterminate.

I cannot figure out how could I manipulate the above to get rid of the indeterminacy.

Comment: Write it $$\frac{x^2 - \sin^2 x}{x^2\sin^2 x}$$ and Taylor-expand the numerator.

Comment: See relevant posts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338411/why-doesnt-using-the-approximation-sin-x-approx-x-near-0-work-for-computin

Comment: And http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/629257/evaluate-mathop-lim-limits-x-to-0-left-1-over-sin-2x-1  (searched from https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%5Crightarrow0%7D(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csin%5E2x%7D-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D)%24&p=1)

Comment: What the other answers don't have:  This limit is a lot easier if you use the trig identity $\sin^x = (1-\cos 2x)/2.$